# Woocommerce Email Custom field not display in table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I created a site in wordpress using woocommerce and i added custom fields in checkout page, also in email after the checkout.

But the problem is custom data **(Delivery Method)** field is not display under the table in email generated by woocommerce.

Please help me to solve this issue.

[image]

**Here is my code**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'my_woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys');

function my_woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys($keys)
{
    $keys['Delivery Method'] = 'delivery_options';
    return $keys;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Robin,

I have tried your problems one solution hope this will be usefull to you.

Solution I tried (And it worked for me)

```
/*This is action hook for adding content before the mail template footer*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', 'custom_email_footer', 10, 1 );

function custom_email_footer( $email ) {
 /*$_POST['billing_delivery_date'] (My custom field variable)*/

 if (isset($_POST['billing_delivery_date'])) { /*Get value of the custom field*/

  /*Echo the filed value with some string or as you want*/
   echo "Delivery date : ".$_POST['billing_delivery_date'];
 }
}
```

- **Understanding**

  > There are several woo-commerce hooks available that can be used to add custom data to the email template sent by mail.
  >
  > NOTE: I also used one of them. :-)

> Also The hook you are using will generate or add the custom field into the email template in the order as per the priority.

- **Screenshot 1**

  > Before used hook / while using your hook : [image: Before Image]
- **Screenshot 2**

  > After Using (woocommerce_email_footer) hook:[image: After image]